# MongoTemplate is not initializing with read only db access privileged user

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Why MongoTemplate is trying to write the document into DB every time when it is initializing?

I just want to  startup my application(initialize MongoTemplate) by connecting with my read only database user.but it is showing error as **not authorized on miamidb to execute command**.eventhough i dont want to write anything to mongo db on startup.

Is there any way to lazy initialize MongoTemplate without creating the document which is not intended to?

Comment: It doesn't write anything on startup. How are you connectin to mongodb can you shoe the code

Comment: connecting through Mongoautoconfiguration which picks up the details from **spring.data.mongodb.uri:** /url property provided on application.yaml.

Comment: got the problem.this was due to **@Indexed** on one of the fileds.@Indexed internally tries to create index **db.COLLECTION_NAME.createIndex({FIELD_NAME: 1})**.So read user fails to startup application.

Comment: Of course. That is possible. If you don't show your code, it is impossible, to guess all possible scenarios. Cheers